# How can I use android Image URI to HTML as background

Tags: android, html

```
How may I assign image to Background in HTML using android URI ?
```

**Code Example:**

```
// Getting images From Camera or Gallery
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);
UserAppSettings.setSplashScreen(imageUri); //Model
}
}
```

**Setting CSS and and Image in Background of Web**

```
//Create String to Change Image Dynamically
public static String htmlDocument = "<html><head><style>.splash {
    background: url('"+UserAppSettings.getSplashScreen()+"');       
}</style><body><div class="splash"></div></body></head></html>";
```

**Putting modified String into JAVA Code:**

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", UserWebPage.htmlDocument,
     "text/html", "UTF-8", ""); 

but this is not working on my side and I am getting Uri very fine
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A52530
```

Comment: You are not setting a value for the src tag. Please show. You are not using your uri for it. Why showing code for a splash screen?

Comment: @greenapps: Thanks for comment, I have changed my question wording